# NSTable insertRowsAtIndexes animation

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I'm calling the `insertRowsAtIndexes` and `removeRowsAtIndexes` to insert or delete from my `NSTableView`, both with animation (`SlideDown` for insert and `SlideUp` for remove), but how can I control so that I can only call insert or remove rows (do a new action) after the animation from the previous has finished?

because I am getting the error:

```
[NSMutableArray insertObjects:atIndexes:]: count of array (25) differs from count of index set (4)
```

If I do add and delete quickly. Or when I fast-click the insert. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

see NSAnimationDelegate
- (void)animationDidEnd:(NSAnimation *)animation

Also, try calling CALayer
- (void)removeAllAnimations before any change.

Another problem with CALayer is that making massive changes can cause all memory to be gobbled up.  Example: importing a massive file, cut/paste massive # of table entries.
For this reason, I enclose massive changes in this block:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
    forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];   
// ... perform massive change
[CATransaction commit];
```